# Resize root partition when using LVM on 14.04

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I have been trying to resize my root partition for several hours now, following multiple guides I found on the Internet.

Installed Ubuntu Server 14.04 on a 8 Gb disk, checked "Use LVM". Then realized that I needed more than 8 Gb.

This is what I have so far:

- I have extended the disk in vCenter
- I have resized /dev/sda2 (extended) and /dev/sda5 (lvm)
- I have booted into the LiveCD and used system-config-lvm to resize the logical root partition to fill /dev/sda properly

Here's my current situation:

```
~  df -h                                 
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/borren--vg-root  6.5G  3.2G  3.1G  52% /
none                         4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                         486M  4.0K  486M   1% /dev
tmpfs                        100M  672K   99M   1% /run
none                         5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none                         497M     0  497M   0% /run/shm
none                         100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                    236M   38M  186M  17% /boot

~  sudo lvs
  LV     VG        Attr      LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  root   borren-vg -wi-ao---   18.76g                                           
  swap_1 borren-vg -wi-ao--- 1020.00m
```

As you can see, root is still just 8 Gb, but at least my LVM partition is now 20 Gb.

What's the next step?

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/borren--vg-root
```

Creds to http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/40702/how-to-manage-and-use-lvm-logical-volume-management-in-ubuntu/